# Assigning sequential numbers as html's IDs

Tags: php

I'm sorry for asking similar question again, but I wanted to make my question short and because of this, your solutions doesn't work for me (I thought it will work in similar way in arrays).

I'm getting photos from xml file:

```
$filelocation=simplexml_load_file('http://path.com/file.xml');
foreach($filelocation->path->attributes() as $photo) {
$position[$flag1]["photos"] .=  "<a id=\"carousel-selector-".$dont-know-what-to-do-here."\"><img src=\"".$photo."\"/></a>";
}
```

It's of course a part of the code which shows photos placed in xml file. What I need is to place unique id to all of them so it will work like:

```
<a id="carousel-selector-0"><img src="http://path.com/link.jpg"/></a>
<a id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="http://path.com/another-link.jpg"/></a>
...
```

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to maintain the **index** for each iteration, as we don't know what will be the **key**, so that we can maintain index outside and will increase the index each time.

```
$filelocation=simplexml_load_file('http://path.com/file.xml');
$index = 0;
foreach($filelocation->path->attributes() as $photo) {
$position[$flag1]["photos"] .=  "<a id=\"carousel-selector-".$index."\"><img src=\"".$photo."\"/></a>";
$index++;
}
```

Comment: we can do this by using `foreach($filelocation->path->attributes() as $key =>  $photo) { 
$position[$flag1]["photos"] .=  "<a id=\"carousel-selector-".$key ."\"><img src=\"".$photo."\"/></a>";
$index++;
}`

Note : In this scenario $key should be indexed  i,e  numeric value.

Comment: Thanks, that actually works, but later, I'm sorting photos by product's price and ID's are mixed :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable to increment :

```
$idx = 0;
foreach($filelocation->path->attributes() as $photo) {
  $position[$flag1]["photos"] .=  "<a id=\"carousel-selector-".($idx++)."\"><img src=\"".$photo."\"/></a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it needs to be any more complicated than maintaining a simple count of how many times you've looped, like this:

```
$filelocation=simplexml_load_file('http://path.com/file.xml');
$count = 0; //loop counter

foreach($filelocation->path->attributes() as $photo) {
  $position[$flag1]["photos"] .=  "<a id=\"carousel-selector-".$count."\"><img src=\"".$photo."\"/></a>"; //use the current count
  $count++; //incremenent the count
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is helpful too, but after the loop, I'm sorting photos by product-price and ID's are getting mixed :(

Comment: you can always upvote it as well if it was useful, even if you don't accept it as the main answer. BTW since we have no idea what your code does following the loop, it's difficult to provide any help with that. Maybe you should ask a fresh question about it.